# Using cloudflare not generating ETag

Tags: http-headers, cloudflare, etag

We are using cloudflare for a simple site and have a problem, that the ETag header is not forwarded.
Cloudflare should support weak ETags by default and we have also set following rules for that site:

[Disable Security, EMail Obfuscication Off, Automatic HTTPS Rewrites Off, Disable Apps, Disable Performance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZUOg.jpg)

However ETags are not shwoing up. Additionally the Content-Length information seems missing.

Comment: Any update on this issue?